# Form as service not working

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-3.2

I have problem with load form as service in Symfony 3.2 i created Custom field as:

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    private $path;

    /**
     * ImageType constructor.
     */
    public function __construct($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return FileType::class;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'image';
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'image_name' => ''
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param FormView $view
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['image_name'] = $options['image_name'];
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->setAttribute('image_name', $options['image_name'])
            ->addModelTransformer(new ImageTransformer($this->path));
    }
}
```

and service.yml:

```
services:
    app.form_image_type:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\ImageType
        arguments: ['%upload_directory%']
        tags: [form.type]
```

But when i run code I have error:

> 2/2 FileLoaderLoadException in FileLoader.php line 118:
>   A "tags" entry must be an array for service "app.form_image_type" in /var/www/exammple.pl/app/config/services.yml. Check your YAML
>   syntax in /var/www/example/app/config/services.yml (which is being
>   imported from "/var/www/example.pl/app/config/config.yml").
>       1/2 InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php line 270:
>       A "tags" entry must be an array for service "app.form_image_type" in /var/www/example.pl/app/config/services.yml. Check your YAML
>   syntax.

But according for docs, tags are defined properly, so have fixed this issue ?

Comment: You are looking at the 3.3 docs in which the tag syntax was simplified.  Switch to the 3.2 doc and follow the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with this code :

```
tags:
   - { name: form.type }
```

look at [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/service_container/tags.html) with 3.2 version